# 403 error while calling Reddit API.

Tags: python, reddit

I'm trying to access data saved by the user. And it keeps returning a 403 error with this being its api end point.

http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_user_{username}_saved

I'm thoroughly confused what to send in my headers to make this request work and the reddit documentation has no mention of it at all. Help?

I'm using Python-requests library to do this.

Comment: And does it send some error message in the body?

Comment: Nothing at all. It just sends error: 403

Comment: Do try it out yourself: http://www.reddit.com/user/{username}/saved/.json It gives the same response.

Comment: try with your own username... and see that it is working...

Answer (score 1):

Referring to line 686 in reddit's code in `listingcontroller.py` ([here](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/controllers/listingcontroller.py#L686)) :

```
    if (where in ('saved', 'hidden') and not 
        ((c.user_is_loggedin and c.user._id == vuser._id) or
          c.user_is_admin)):
        return self.abort403()
```

you can clearly see that you must be logged in as `username` or be an admin in order to get the `saved` or `hidden` data - otherwise you get a `403 error`.

Comment: But this is an API call. I get the part of logged in, but why I can't send username/password/anything else in the parameters and get access to the api data? If not, then how is it an API call?

Comment: Yes. this is the code for the api calls as well, only add `.json` or `.xml` at the end...

Comment: Yes, I got that part. But I'm confused what the parameters have to be for reddit's api to consider that I'm logged in. What headers/parameters does it want along with the request?

Answer (score 0):

As @zenpoy already mentioned (and which you already know), you have to be logged in. Therefore, you should save the cookie, which you get as a response of a valid call to `api/login`. I've written some code, which logs a user in and retrieves all saved things:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import json

login_url = 'https://ssl.reddit.com/api/login/'
saved_url = 'https://ssl.reddit.com/user/<username>/saved.json'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))


def login(username, passwd):
    values = {'user': username,
              'api_type': 'json',
              'passwd': passwd}

    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    response = opener.open(login_url, data).read()

    print json.loads(response)


def retrieve_saved(username):
    url = saved_url.replace('<username>', username)
    response = opener.open(url).read()

    print json.loads(response)


login(<username>, <passwd>)
retrieve_saved(<username>)
```